# How do I run a web application "offline" on my Android?

Tags: browser, offline

I have a web application written using HTML5 that leverages the application cache for "offline" access.

On my iPod touch, I can go to the web while online, click the "+" icon, and set a shortcut on my home screen. This will launch the web application full screen and run the app, even when there is no Internet connection.

Is there a similar process to use on my Android device, or will it vary by maker?

Comment: This sounds like a question for [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: hehe, first SU closed it, now AE is going to bounce me to SO? I thought it was simpler than this! 8^D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Offline data saving is supported on Android, you can see this if you go into your browser, select Settings, Advanced Settings, Website Settings and you can see which websites are using your offline cache, as well as which are using other advanced access like GPS.

To create an icon for a website on your home screen: once you've created a bookmark in your browser for the page, you can go to your home screen, long-press on a bit of spare space, select Shortcuts, Bookmark and pick that one. That should give you an icon straight to that page.

Comment: Thanks! The "full screen" mode might be an iPhone only thing, but I was able to verify the app worked from the icon while the phone was in airplane mode.

Answer (score 2):

From my HTML5 knowledge, offline content and access, even though implemented by the website, will only work if the browser the client is using supports it. The iOS browser seems to support offline applications, but the Android one does not yet, based on what you said. So you will jsut have to wait until the browser is updated.

Comment: Offline data saving is supported on Android, go into your browser, Settings, Advanced Settings, Website Settings and you can see which websites are using your offline cache, as well as which are using other advanced access like GPS.

Comment: @GAThrawn I was able to check that, and I verified the app worked in "airplane" mode on a Samsung Fascinate last night. I was looking more for how to get the "home page screen" link to work and if there was a way to have it open the app in a "full screen mode" like it does on the iPhone/iPod touch.

Comment: @Dillie-O Once you've created a bookmark in your browser for the page, you can go to your home screen, long-press on a bit of spare space, select Shortcuts, Bookmark and pick that one. That should give you an icon straight to that page. Not owning an iPhone I'm not sure what you mean by full screen, all web pages are full screen aren't they?

Comment: @GAThrawn You should migrate your comments to an answer. This is what I've been looking for. As for the "full screen" mode, it functions similar to the "web app" mode in Chrome where it strips the navigation header/footer elements and just runs the app that way for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this app: Offline Browser [link](http://www.appbrain.com/app/offline-browser/it.nikodroid.offline): you can download a portion of a web site in your sd card and then read it offline